# Quasar q-form reset doesn't clear the values in the form

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm using quasar q-forms and I want the 'Reset' button to clear both the values and the validation.

It doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Here is my component:

```
<q-form
      ref="sampleRef"
      @submit="onSubmit"
      @reset="onReset"            
      class="q-gutter-md"
    >
      <q-input
        filled
        v-model="name"
        label="Your name *"
        hint="Name and surname"
        :rules="[ val => val && val.length > 0 || 'Please type something']"
      ></q-input>

      <q-input
        filled
        type="number"
        v-model="age"
        label="Your age *"
        :rules="[
          val => val !== null && val !== '' || 'Please type your age',
          val => val > 0 && val < 100 || 'Please type a real age'
        ]"
      ></q-input>

      <q-toggle v-model="accept" label="I accept the license and terms"></q-toggle>

      <div>
        <q-btn label="Submit" type="submit" color="primary"></q-btn>
        <q-btn label="Reset" type="reset" color="primary" flat class="q-ml-sm"></q-btn>
      </div>
    </q-form>
```

```
const sampleRef = ref(null)

onReset () {
   sampleRef.value.reset()
   sampleRef.value.resetValidation()
}
```

It only resets the validation, but the values are retained.
I don't want to manually clear all the fields, since I'd have a lot of fields in my q-form.

Here is a sample codepen:
https://codepen.io/keechan/pen/GRLqXZE?editors=1011

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [Quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/form#usage) says:

> If you want to take advantage of the reset functionality, then be
> sure to also capture the @reset event on QForm and make its handler
> reset all of the wrapped components models.

You can see in the first example code that they explicitly set each model value to `null`:

```
onReset () {
    name.value = null
    age.value = null
    accept.value = false
}
```

If you wanted to do this without resetting each value, then one option would be to keep all the fields in a single object and replace it in the reset function.

```
const initial = {
    name: null,
    age: null,
    accept: false
};
    
const formModel = ref({...initial});

///...

onReset () {
    formModel.value = {...initial};
    //...
}


<q-input
    v-model="formModel.name"
//etc
```